Defining binomial coefficient on $\mathbb F_p((t))$.
Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field, $A=\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers, $\pi$ be its prime (uniformizer) and $k=\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_k$ be its residue field. Recall that $\mathcal F_\pi$ is the set of $f(X)\in A[[x]]$ such that $f(X)=\pi X +\text{higher terms}$ and $f(X)\equiv x^q \pmod{\pi}$ where $q=\#k$.
For each $f\in \mathcal F_\pi$, let $F_f$ be its Lubin-Tate group law. We know that for every $a\in A$, there is an unique endomorphism $[a]_f:F_f\to F_f$ such that $[a]_f=aT+\text{terms of degree} \geq 2$ and $[a]_f\circ f= f\circ [a]_f$.
In the case $K=\mathbb Q_p$, where $f=(1+T)^p-1\in \mathcal F_p$, we can choose
$$[a]_f=(1+T)^a-1$$
where $\binom{a}{i}\in \mathbb Z_p$ can be define as $\lim \binom{a_j}{i}$ with a integer sequence $(a_j)\to a \in \mathbb Z_p$ as $j\to \infty$.
How can I define similar binomial coefficients in the case $K=\mathbb F_p((t))$? Let $a\in A=\mathbb F_p[[t]]$, how can I construct $[a]_f$ when $f(X)=(1+T)^p-1$?

Do not try to force the use of $f()=(1+T)^p − 1$ in characteristic $p$, since it equals $T^p$.  This is not a Lubin-Tate series in characteristic $p$, or even in characteristic zero unless $K = \mathbf Q_p$ since you need $p$ to be a uniformizer in $K$ and you need the residue field to have size $p$, so $[K:\mathbf Q_p] = ef = 1\cdot 1 = 1$.
Instead, see here (especially examples in Section 5, where pages 14 and 15 discuss Lubin-Tate coefficient functions, including in characteristic $p$) and here.

I understand it now. The structure I'm looking for is called $\textit{the Carlitz polynomial}$, it is obviously not a simple structure as on $\mathbb Q_p$. Thank you!
